# I have three arrays: source, destination and charges. I want to get charges for a particular source and destination

Tags: php

```
source = ["hyderabd","banglore","hyderabad","chennai","pune","mumbai"];
destination = ["pune","chennai","mumbai","hyderabad","banglore","hyderabad"];
prices = ["500","300","400","600","500","500"];
```

I have source and destination variables:
    src="hyderabad" & des="mumbai"

I want to get price from hyderabad to mumbai which is 400 from prices array.

How can i get this?

Comment: You should use a 'journey' array of objects. With each object having keys for source, destination and price.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using foreach loop:

```
$source = ["hyderabd","banglore","hyderabad","chennai","pune","mumbai"];
$destination = ["pune","chennai","mumbai","hyderabad","banglore","hyderabad"];
$prices = ["500","300","400","600","500","500"];
foreach($prices as $key => $price) {
  // Array keys as string for source and destination.
  $srcToDest = $source[$key] . " -> " . $destination[$key];
  $charges[$srcToDest] = $price;
}
echo "<pre>"; print_r($charges);
```

The output will be:

```
Array
(
    [hyderabd -> pune] => 500
    [banglore -> chennai] => 300
    [hyderabad -> mumbai] => 400
    [chennai -> hyderabad] => 600
    [pune -> banglore] => 500
    [mumbai -> hyderabad] => 500
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to find the index of an element

```
echo $prices[array_search("hyderabad", $source)]; // 400
```

However, this seems rather random. What happens if the source and destination entries don't have the same index as the price? How do source and destination relate to prices? What are you actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: this will not work as its independet of destination. All the 3 arrays will have same length

Comment: Sure, but what happens if I'm travelling from Bangalore to Mumbai? How do you personally know what the correct price is?

Answer (score 0):

use of array_column() you get your result

`````
$all[]=$source = ["hyderabd","banglore","hyderabad","chennai","pune","mumbai"];
$all[]=$destination = ["pune","chennai","mumbai","hyderabad","banglore","hyderabad"];
$all[]=$prices = ["500","300","400","600","500","500"];
$search =   array_column($all, '2');
print_r($search);
?>

````
`````

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the source, destination and prices, you should probably store them in a different format, not three separate arrays. You could probably store this like so:

```
$prices[$source][$destination] = $price;
```

So with your input this becomes:

```
$prices['hyderabad']['pune'] = 500;
$prices['hyderabad']['mumbai'] = 400;
$prices['banglore']['chennai'] = 300;
$prices['chennai']['hyderabad'] = 600;
$prices['pune']['banglore'] = 500;
$prices['mumbai']['hyderabad'] = 500;
```